# Installing libx11-devel from source, error in string.h

Tags: x11, software-installation, non-root-user, source

I'm running

```
Linux version 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b9.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)
```

and trying to install libX11-devel from source on a machine where I don't have root access (with the end goal of runnning [CERN's ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/)).

However, I've been getting this error when processing lib/libXau

```
      CC     AuDispose.lo
In file included from $HOME/include/X11/Xfuncs.h:46:0,
                 from ./include/X11/Xauth.h:57,
                 from AuDispose.c:30:
/usr/include/string.h:548:5: error: unknown type name ‘__locale_t’
     __locale_t __loc)
     ^
/usr/include/string.h:552:18: error: unknown type name ‘__locale_t’
      size_t __n, __locale_t __loc)
                  ^
```

I see other people usually have this error while building GCC, and the problem is resolved by downloading a newer version, but I've tried that and haven't had any luck. What is causing this error?

Comment: It looks like you may have a formatting / copy&paste error on the last line of your error message block.  Please check (and [edit], if necessary): does the `^` point to the `__n` or the `__locale_t`?

Comment: Ah, thanks. It wasn't indented with the code block, so it was 4 spaces off. Does that lend any insight?

Comment: Sorry, no, I can't answer this; I just wanted to make sure that the question was clear, for the benefit of people who might be able to help you.